# Is it possible to run R from a tablet using Honeycomb (Android 3.0)?

Tags: android, r, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet

I have a Xoom tablet and it would be great if I could run statistical analysis using R on it. [As far as I know](http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/06/could-we-run-a-statistical-analysis-on-iphoneipad-using-r/) it is not possible to use R on iPad due to license problems (GPl x iTunes etc.) and a lack of compiler for Fortran in the Apple tablet.

But what about tablets using android? Arguably, the GPL issue is not a problem, so any help here on how to use R on my tablet?

Comment: Any news on this question? (now for Android 4)

Comment: Not from me... But It's been a while since I tried to use R with Android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At some point, smartphones and tablets will have browsers capable enough to run [RStudio](http://rstudio.org) in its server mode via the browser.  Currently, the latter demands too much in terms of newer GWT, Javascricpt, ... magic that it remains limited to (recent enough) desktop browsers; see [here](http://www.rstudio.org/docs/advanced/optimizing_browser) for a bit more on this.

You can always ssh out though.  [Connectbot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/) is a capable ssh client for Android, and of course free.  No graphs though.

Comment: Running R from a server woudl move us to cloud computing... Any thoughts about how this woudlchange our way of perform statistical analysis?

Comment: The webkit browser in Android 3.0 is a lot like chrome, and has some of the same technologies backing it (the javascript engine, V8)

Comment: Manoel: No, running R from a server is not the same as cloud computing.  Many of us run R on a server (say, in 64 bit) and simply use `ssh` to get there.  Using it in a browser is arguably a little more cloud-ish, but many of us have done decoupled client/server like work with R for many years.

Comment: Jon: Thanks for the update. Maybe Android 3.0 will be good enough--we'll see!  Have a poke around at RStudio's site if you want to learn more. They are a friendly bunch.

Comment: @Dirk, yep, running from a server is not the same as cloud computing. I was imprecise. And I didn't know about this 'ssh' stuff. What's that? Thanks again.

Comment: Manoel, the first hit of *ssh* in Google gets you a link to one of the [reference implementation](http://www.openssh.com), the second hit gets you the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) with background information.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I can test RStudio hosted on a server with my Xoom's browser. Let me know!

Comment: @Jon It helps me! But I guess I can test too. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: And @Dirk, thanks for the links. Next time I'll do the proper search before asking. I was a bit lazy...

Comment: Hi, I'm one of the RStudio devs. RStudio doesn't work on iOS or Android because of lack of support of contentEditable. However, it's conceivable that we could work around this limitation in the future with a fair amount of work. Not our highest priority at the moment though.

Comment: @JoeCheng `contenteditable` is supported on iOS 5-> Having R accessible on the iPhone/Android/iPad would be great for school.

Answer (score 13):

I used Linux Installer from http://android.galoula.com/en/LinuxInstall/ (my Dezire Z was rooted beforehand), installed stable debian and R! on this Linux install. I`m not a Linux-geek and total time for installation (first time loop file size was insufficient, and I repeated the whole process) wass less than hour however.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/ed66fabfa5a7ba0631495c96b6f4ba77.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) offers developers the facility to program in Java, ... not  <s>C or</s>   Fortran, which are the languages in which R is written. Although some have said that [hacking the Android tablets voids their warranty and  prevents upgrades](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-hack-motorola-xoom-android-tablet-rooting-guide-0125671/), Motorola only requires that the device be relocked before doing upgrades. For this question I think it still boils down to "if you have to ask the question,  then *you* cannot do it".

EDIT: But somebody else will probably try it.

<s>(I haven't found gcc for the Android.)</s>

Comment: that article you linked to is terrible and incorrect about not being able to LTE upgrade.

also, the NDK allows development in C++. Last time I checked, C is a subset of C++.

Comment: What I read says there is an Android specific version of C called Bionic, which has been noted to be incompatible with standard C code. If you have evidence that refutes the assertions in the article you should cite it rather than just asserting it to be "terrible".

Comment: I was referring to the outdated/faulty information about the Xoom's warranty in that article. I didn't see anything about Bionic.

Comment: And how are we to know that the article is "outdated" or "faulty"?

Comment: @DWin GCC for Android is included with the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html). Talking about lockdown in your answer is not particularly helpful, as unlike Apple, Google does not constrain what development tools or runtime systems you use in your applications. Now, I don't know to what extent R relies on Fortran, or how easy it would be to port to Android, since the NDK is somewhat limited compared to a normal Linux/glibc system. However, those would just be technical limitations, not the system being locked down.