# Are there any Android version of R (without rooting the device)?

Tags: android, r

Are there any version/equivalent of [R](http://www.r-project.org/) for android platform, specifically a `.apk` file?

If not, how do one build it from the [source](http://cran.r-project.org/sources.html), without *rooting* the device?

(R is a free software environment for statistical computing and graphics. It compiles and runs on a wide variety of UNIX platforms, Windows and MacOS.)

Comment: Can you explain more your question? R is an automatically generated Class that maps your layout to unique Ids, so what do you mean by versions/equivalent? If you mean system resources, you can access them from android.R class

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah Added a clarification note and relevant link.

Comment: Almost identical question: [Is it possible to run R from a tablet using Honeycomb (Android 3.0)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702028/is-it-possible-to-run-r-from-a-tablet-using-honeycomb-android-3-0). On second thoughts - this is identical - the answers in linked question contain instructions for doing this.

Comment: I found [this howto](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=getting-started:installation:android) on how to build R for android. The site provides both, compiled binaries and the source code. The problem with most applications is that they require a glibc whereass android only provides a straped down (minimal) version of the glibc which is not compatible. This leads to a lot of adaption work needed. In fact this article does not provide a very good solution: The installation requires root access to the devices and the author does not provide a patch which explains the modifications which are ne

Comment: @Andrie Thanks for pointing out, please vote to close. However I would like to make some edits to question; in the light of the question and the answers there.

Answer (score 9):

I'll add one answer to this already a bit dated question, since things have developed a bit in the last year or so.

You can install R locally on an Android device using the GNURoot software that is available from the Google Play. Despite it's name, GNURoot does not require rooting the device. I outlined the installation process in a few more details in my blog at http://www.r-ohjelmointi.org/?p=1434.

There is also R-Fiddle (http://www.r-fiddle.org/) that you can use through browser, and if you can connect to a WLAN while on a journey, it might be worth testing, also.

Answer (score 3):

RStudio server is one possibility, you could that from a tablet - http://goo.gl/PAEvR

Comment: Thank you, Ricardo, but want to use R while offline or on a journey.

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham carry an ultraBook with lots of battery.

Comment: *This site is closed.*

Comment: seems link is broken