# How to call a custom R script using Android?

Tags: r, opencpu

I'm looking to build an Android app which calls an R script on clicking a button. I don't know how to get an R script to run using Android. I tried using openCPU but couldn't get ahead with it. Can anyone tell me how to call a custom R script using Android?

Comment: I cannot tell what is being asked. How does the R statistical language relate to Android devices?

Comment: Did you install `R` on android ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968411/installing-r-on-android