# Calling r from java - android application

Tags: java, android, r

My group is working on an android application which must:
-query a database
-modify some of the data returned
-pass the data to r for some statistical analysis (do a boxcox)
-receive the result as a vector

Can this be done with JRI? Is it even possible to utilize R in an android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing native built in. But referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702028/is-it-possible-to-run-r-from-a-tablet-using-honeycomb-android-3-0) thread you may have the possibilty to send your data to a server where the data are computed and send the results back?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the R that is the list of integer references in Android?  It's certainly accessible, but is read only.

ie.

```
R.id.my_item
R.string.my_string
R.color.my_color
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm referring to the statistical software R.